# SharePoint 2010 REST /_vti_bin/ListData.svc issue

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

we have a SharePoint 2010 website and we are facing an issue with /_vti_bin/listdata.svc REST API.

`http://SiteName/en/_vti_bin/listdata.svc` - works fine

`http://SiteName/en/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/FAQs` or any other listName - works fine

but it is not working when switch to arabic site

`http://SiteName/ar/_vti_bin/listdata.svc` - works fine

`http://SiteName/ar/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/FAQs` or any other listName - not working (it shows that "The webpage cannot be found" even the list is 100% exist under both labels (en & ar))

the site uses SharePoint Variation.
SharePoint build numbers is: 14.0.6123.5000, Arabic language pack is installed , and SP1 for Arabic language pack is installed.
OS: windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Please try after removing ar from the URL.

```
http://SiteName/_vti_bin/listdata.svc

http://SiteName/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/FAQs
```

Comment: thank you for your response... all lists under root site (http://SiteName/_vti_bin/listdata.svc) are working...  but all lists under /ar/ are not working, removing /ar/ did not work

Answer (score 0):

The URL containing web part is correct. It works well for me on non-english webs even on variation webs. The only thing I realized is that you must use display name of the list and not his URL and moreover the name is case and accent sensitive.

Comment: thank you for your response, I do use the display name with accent sensitive, i have found today that it shows the below error on Chrome browser:` <error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code/>
<message xml:lang="ar-AE">Syntax error 'ّ' at position 5.</message>
</error> `

Comment: It seems like Chrome is not able to parse the result returned by the service. While testing I noticed one more strange thing. I created list named číح but I had to use /Číح at the end of URL. It seems that service capitalize first letter of the list name.

Comment: yes that's right, the service capitalize first letter of the list name...
i am running out of solutions, nothing worked for this issue....
Please tell me what updates you are using in your environment? maybe installing some updates will fix the issue.

Comment: I'm running SP 2010 with SP2 14.0.7015.1000. Maybe one more tip. Try to URL encode your list name into URL. I noticed that SP returned me reference to that list with encoded list name. In my test it was like this: http://server/webs/site/web/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/%C4%8C%C3%AD%D8%AD/

Comment: unfortunately, Installing SP2 and Updates and encoding list name did not fixed the issue. I would like to extend a big thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

it seems this is a Bug in the system as I have been facing this issue for over a month in Office 365 and I opened a support ticket with Microsoft and they confirmed it's a bug and they will provide a hotfix for It in Office 365. I suggest you do the same by opening a ticket as you have on-premise SharePoint.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, we already opened a support ticket with Microsoft, but they did not provide any answer regarding the issue yet.